# How come KSQLDB push query outputs chunked json?

Tags: ksqldb

I'm new to KsqlDB so I might be missing something obvious. My question is related to the chunked JSON output of a never-ending push-query not being valid JSON. Let me elaborate.

In short, my setup is as follows. From a typescript/node process I've created a push query on a ksql stream as such:

```
CREATE STREAM events (id VARCHAR, timestamp VARCHAR, location VARCHAR, events ARRAY<VARCHAR>) WITH (kafka_topic='mytopic', value_format='json', partitions=1);
```

The push query itself is created as a long-running REST stream (using axios):

```
const response = await axios.post(
    `http://ksqldb-server:8088/query-stream`,
    {
        sql: `SELECT * FROM events EMIT CHANGES;`,
        streamsProperties: {}
    },
    {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.ksql.v1+json',
            Accept: 'application/vnd.ksql.v1+json',
        },
        responseType: 'stream',
    }
);
```

This works. When run, I first get the header row:

```
[{"header":{"queryId":"transient_EVENTS_2815830975103425962","schema":"`ID` STRING, `TIMESTAMP` STRING, `LOCATION` STRING, `EVENTS` ARRAY<STRING>"}}
```

Followed by new rows coming in one-by-one based on real-world events:

```
{"row":{"columns":["b82baad7-a87e-4617-b18a-1782b4cb49ce","2022-05-16 08:03:03","Home",["EventA","EventD"]]}},\n
```

Now, if this query would ever complete it would probably end up as valid JSON when concatenated together (although the header row is missing a `,` at the end). Since it's a push query however, it never completes and as such I won't receive the closing `]` - which means it will never be valid JSON. Also, I'm looking to process events in real-time, otherwise I could have written a pull query instead.

My expectations were that each new row would be parseble by itself using `JSON.parse()`. Instead, I've ended up having to `JSON.parse(data.slice(0, -2))` to get rid of the additional `,\n`. However, it does not feel right to put this into production.

What is the rational behind outputting chunked JSON on push queries? It seems an illogical format to me for any use-case.

And is there a way to alter the output of ksql events to what I would expect? Maybe some header or attribute I'm missing?

Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly set `application/vnd.ksql.v1+json` as your desired response format in the headers:

```
headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.ksql.v1+json',
            Accept: 'application/vnd.ksql.v1+json',
        },
```

`application/vnd.ksql.v1+json` means that the complete response will be a valid JSON doc.

As you pointed out, this is impractical as the push query never completes. You should remove the headers or set them explicitly to the default `application/vnd.ksqlapi.delimited.v1`. `application/vnd.ksqlapi.delimited.v1` means that the every returned row is going to be valid JSON.

See https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-rest-api/streaming-endpoint/#executing-pull-or-push-queries for more details.